# How to style a Polymer element from the main stylesheet?

Tags: html, css, polymer, polymer-2.x

I'm using [`<paper-progress-button>`](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/Collaborne/paper-progress-button/elements/paper-progress-button) in a project, and I want to style it from my main stylesheet but can't get it to work.

The styling code for `<paper-progress-button>` looks like this:

```
<dom-module id="paper-progress-button">

    <template>
        <style>
            :host {
                display: inline-block;
            }

            .button {
                @apply --paper-progress-button-button;
            }

            .button:not([disabled]) {
                @apply --paper-progress-button-button-active;
            }

            .spinner {
                margin-left: 10px;
                @apply --paper-progress-button-spinner;
            }

            [hidden] {
                display: none;
            }
        </style>

        ...
```

I've tried all sorts of ways to get my styles from a main site-level stylesheet to affect the button, but none seem to work:

**main.css**

```
--paper-progress-button-button {
    background-color: red;
}
```

**main.css**

```
* {
    --paper-progress-button-button {
        background-color: red;
    };
}
```

**custom_style.html**

```
<custom-style>
    <style is="custom-style">
        --paper-progress-button-button {
            background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
</custom-style>
```

**custom_style.html**

```
<custom-style>
    <style is="custom-style">
        :root {
            --paper-progress-button-button {
                background-color: red;
            };
        }
    </style>
</custom-style>
```

The [documentation for styling Polymer 2](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/style-shadow-dom#examples) is huge, but doesn't even mention `@apply` once! So how do I really style that button from my site-level stylesheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polymer currently only shims CSS properties within a `custom-style` or a Polymer element's `style`; and not from an external stylesheet.

Also note the style usage is incorrect, as the CSS property name must be followed by a colon:

```
.my-div {
  --paper-progress-button-button: {
    background-color: red;
  };
}
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/zpQBPj?editors=1010)

Comment: This solved it - I was missing the colon. Putting `paper-progress-button {
            --paper-progress-button-button: {
                background-color: red;
            }
        }` in a main `<custom-style>` element which is imported in the main document works fine now.